# After restoring all of my files are sitting under my documents. How can i clean up?

Tags: mac, photos, music, macos

I had to erase and reinstall everything on my macbook pro.  I was having issues restoring from timeline so I did a manual copy over from an external hard drive onto my computer.

The issue is that I don't see the Pictures, Music or Movies folders in Finder any more so I just put all of my files inside "My Documents".

I thought that itunes would reorganize my files when i imported everything into itunes but it doesn't seem like it as the machines still thinks i have 200+ GB of documents. (see screenshots) and it doesn't show any movies or music.

[image]

So my questions are:

1. how can i get these other folders (Music, Movies) to show up in My Finder (on the left side bar)
2. what is the "right" place to store my music, pictures, movies (assuming sitting in "My documents" isn't correct

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to Finder's preferences, then to the sidebar tab to re-enable folders on the sidebar.

The correct place to put

- Pictures: Pictures folder
- iTunes: Music folder
- Videos: Movies folder
- Documents: Documents

Comment: You can also just drag them into the sidebar.

Comment: @MacManager yes, but that's assuming the OP can get to their home folder, which they don't seem to know how.